# layout-xml isn't used / updated

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, css, layout-update, skin

I have a theme in my package, that handles special products/pages. Therefore I have copy-pasted the file bundle.xml to the folder `app>...>layout>my_package>my_theme>bundle.xml` and in there I do put (besides other stuff) this:

```
 <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Bundle)</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bundle.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bundle.css</name></action>
        </reference>
</PRODUCT>
```

And I have 2 problems now with that:

**1.** `The bundle.js-file is taken from the base>default-package (what doesn't bother me any further)`
 2.

```
The bundle-css-file isn't taken at all. Although the file is put into skin>frontend>my_package>my_theme>css>bundle.css
```

I defined the use of my_theme within the needed pages and it uses all specially changed .phtml-files, but that one here is the only change that is actually done on the skins' folder. Do I need to put something additional on the dashboard or don't I get the point?

Comment: skin_js and skin_css have the same way skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}
check if there are in your folders necessary files. Do you see in browser:view_source_code links to your files?

Comment: bundle.css is in the correspong correct theme-folder. bundle.js not. And as said, in my sourcecode I see a reference-link to base-defaults' bundle.js but not for the bundle.css - file

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% this affects but your closing tag in bundle.xml might need to be `</PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>` as opposed to just `</PRODUCT>`